# How to use notifier() together with composing()?

Tags: c++, boost

I have C++ code which uses declaration of options with help of:

```
boost::program_options::option_descriptions::add_options()
```

I need to add checks for every option value against regular expression and additional checks.

I decide to use notifier() for this purpose. For example:

```
add_options()
("myoption", bpo::value<string>()->notifier(param_validator()), "My option description")
;
```

where param_validator is functional object and it validates option value.

I have another options which already uses composing() for example:

```
("myoption2", bpo::value<string>()->composing(), "My option 2 description")
```

What is syntax for calling notifier() for the same option ?
Or can be called notifier() at all for such option ?

Answer (score 1):

The `composing` member has a `notifier` member. So you would just call `notifier` from `composing`. Working example:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>
namespace po = boost::program_options;

int main()
{
    using str_vect_type = std::vector<std::string>;
    size_t cmdcnt = 5;
    const char* cmdline[] = { "dmy.exe", "--myoption", "this_that", "--myoption2", "testing" };
    auto param_validator = [](const std::string& x) {std::cout << " " << x <<  "\nparam_validator\n"; };
    auto other = [](const str_vect_type& x) {for (auto& s : x)std::cout << " " << s << '\n'; std::cout << "the_other\n"; };
    po::variables_map vm;
    try {

        po::options_description desc("Allowed options");
        desc.add_options()
            ("myoption", po::value<std::string>()->notifier(param_validator), "My option description")
            ("myoption2", po::value<std::vector<std::string> >()->composing()->notifier(other), "My option 2 description")
            ;
        po::store(po::parse_command_line(cmdcnt, cmdline, desc), vm);
        //as if from ini file hack...
        const_cast<str_vect_type*>(&vm["myoption2"].as<str_vect_type>())->push_back("another");
        po::notify(vm);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "error: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```